# gdb get different structure size when command run twice

Tags: c, gdb

I have a program run in such a way:
process A  ---write-->global structure---read by--->process B
whereas process B can't get what A once written
Using GDB, I found something weird like that:
[image]

Can any one explain why this happen?

Comment: there's something wrong with the picture,the text was like this:(gdb) p sizeof(struct rte_eth_stats)
$1 = 704
(gdb)  p sizeof(pstat_dpdk[2])
$2 = 808
(gdb) p sizeof(struct rte_eth_stats)
$3 = 808

Comment: the problem's solved. one structure defined in a c file and another defined in the header file.    still another problem:where do gdb get the size of the structure so that the result  changed when the "P sizeof(my_struct)" called twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can any one explain why this happen?

As you've already discovered, this is the result of violating the one definition rule -- you have the same struct defined different way in different parts of your program.

The specific GDB behavior is explained like so: GDB does not *eagerly* parse debug info until it needs to (it does so *lazily*).

When you execute the first `print sizeof(struct rte_eth_stats)`, GDB finds the first definition of `rte_eth_stats` (it may already have loaded this definition earlier depending on which commands you have executed up to that point).

When you execute the second `print sizeof(pstat_dpdk[2])`, GDB looks up the definition of `pstat_dpdk`, and *in doing so* discovers the *second* definition of `rte_eth_stats`, and updates its notion of what that struct is.

When you execute the third `print`, GDB uses the updated state of `rte_eth_stats`, and prints its "new" size.

GDB could have printed a warning when replacing the first definition of `rte_eth_stats` with the second if the two definitions have different size.

However, it is not uncommon to have such differing definitions (e.g. where clients of a library only know about first (say) 3 members of struct, but the library itself knows about additional (private) members), and printing a warning in that case would be annoying.

Answer (score 0):

There's not a lot of details to go on in your question, but making some assumptions, let me ask: Are these two programs compiled against the same headers?

If the header files used to compile each program differ, sizeof(struct) in each might differ.

Comment: two much header file are involved, but i checked for the related structure member as long as the marcos,they should be defined in the same place